# ProtonVPN no longer showing up on applications menu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, launcher

I've used Proton VPN in the past, but now it's suddenly not listed under my programs menu / application launcher.
I'm pretty sure it's still installed because I see it updating when I'm doing updates.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep proton
```

and it responded:

```
protonvpn-stable-release/unknown,now 1.0.3-2 all [installed]
```

I also tried:

```
dpkg --list | grep proton
```

and it returned:

```
protonvpn-stable-release
```

So I think it's still installed, I just don't see the icon.

I was thinking I could start it from the terminal but it didn't work when I typed:
`protonvpn` or `protonvpn-stable-release`.
It said:

```
command not found
```

Is there a way to refresh the app launcher so it will show the ProtonVPN icon again?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but for their beta release (which may be packaged differently), the `protonvpn-beta-release` package installs only the apt repo definitions.

The actual application is in `proton-vpn-gnome-desktop`. If they've organised the stable release in the same way, then you would need to install that package.

In my installation, the binary is `protonvpn-app`.

Comment: There isn't a .desktop file for Proton so I have to create one myself.
How do you find the name of the executable to put at Exec=/path/to/executable in the .desktop file? 
"which protonvpn" doesn't return anything.

Comment: Two ways: I typed `protonvpn<TAB>` in bash and this autocompleted to `protonvpn-app`. Then to find out which package it came from `dpkg -S protonvpn-app`. Also, there is a desktop file: `dpkg -S 'proton*.desktop'` (note this is a glob, not a regex) gives `proton-vpn-gtk-app: /usr/share/applications/protonvpn-app.desktop`.

Comment: Did you actually install `proton-vpn-gnome-desktop` as my answer above says? That should have given you both the executable and the desktop file (through the package shown in my previous comment). No need for manual mucking about.

Comment: Yeah, installing roton-vpn-gnome-desktop worked. Last time the package I installed was just called protonvpn.